# Is there a thesaurus-like reference for generalizings of terms by common type?

Tags: reference

For example - "First, second, third, ..." generalize to "ordinal numbers". "Primary, secondary, tertiary, ..." are "rankings".

Is there a well known reference for meaning-based categorizations?

Comment: Even this seems unlikely to me: **"Primary, secondary, tertiary..." are "rankings".**  My dictionary has "tertiary: third in order or level.  Thus *primary, secondary, tertiary,...* would be *orders* or *levels*.

Comment: Please edit to provide an example of “meaning-based categorizations”. Your examples relating to ordinal numbers and rankings have an intrinsic numeric ordering. Lexicographical ordering can apply to spelling-based categorisation. But it’s not clear to me what kind of ordering you are thinking of for meaning-based (semantic) categorisations. For example, (A) table-cloth, napkin; (B) chair, table, cow. A = cloth or cloth-like objects, B = things with legs. What ordering do you have in mind between A and B?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)